A person deposits 500$ every month. If the rate of annual compound interest is 10% and the period is 4 How much money will be received after 3 years?
This question isn't hard but it is very long.
The period is 4 which means interest will be received and be added to the deposit every 12/4=3 months.
For example, The first time deposit after 3 months is $500*3=1500$. Let the interest on that amount be $(I)= \frac{ptr}{100}$ [p=deposited amount=1500, t=time=1/4 year,r=the rate of compound interest=10%]
Putting in the values we get $\frac{1500*0.25*10}{100}=37.5$
After another three months we will have to calculate like this with principle $1500+1500+37.5=3037.5$
I had to calculate one after another like this 12 times and the solution was long.
Is there any way to solve this in a shorter way?

Look up Arithmetico-Geometric Sequence, or calculate using a spreadsheet. Minor clarification needed: is interest paid on the 3rd 6th,... month following each deposit, or on each March/June/Sept/Dec (in which case you need to specify the month of the first deposit)?

A formula (that you should probably know if given that assignment) exists to calculate it directly.

Well, it's actually fairly simple since the amount of money you deposit every quarter is the same. Call it $PMT$. The interest added after each period would be $i=\frac{10\%}{4}$ with a total number of payoffs equal to $N=\frac{\text{3 years }\cdot \text{12 months }}{\text{each 3 monhts}} = 12$.
The current value of deposited money yields $CM \cdot i$ of interest, so the total money after each period is $CM + CM \cdot i = CM \cdot (1 + i)$.
Starting with the value $PMT$ you have for each period:
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
n=1: PMT&\cdot(1+i) \\
n=2: (PMT\cdot(1+i) + PMT )&\cdot(1+i)  = PMT\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{2}(1+i)^{k}\\
n=3: (PMT\cdot(1+i)^{2} + PMT\cdot(1+i) + PMT )&\cdot(1+i)  = PMT\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{3}(1+i)^{3}\\
\dots \\
n=N: (PMT\cdot{(1+i)}^{N-1} + PMT\cdot{(1+i)}^{N-2}+ \dots + PMT) &\cdot(1+i) = PMT\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{N}\cdot{(1+i)}^{k} \\
\end{array}
$$
It takes the knowldege of school maths to recognise the sum of a geometric progression:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{N}\cdot{(1+i)}^{k} = 
(1+i)\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\cdot{(1+i)}^{k} =
(1+i)\cdot \frac{(1+i)^{N}-1}{(1+i)-1} = (1+i)\cdot\frac{(1+i)^{N}-1}{i}
$$
Note, though, that the interest pays off each 3 months, so the $PMT=3\cdot500\$$ which you have figured out yourself.
Finally:
$$
\text{Money Received} = 3\cdot500\$ \cdot \frac{(1+0.025)}{0.025} \cdot((1+0.025)^{12}-1) \approx 1500\$ \cdot 14.14 = 21,210\$.
$$
